# How to Force DI style

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

We are building a ASP.NET MVC 5 web application.
We can use using an IoC container to resolve service dependency but still new/ignorant developers can create instance of service classes while they need and not resolving it using DI framework.

Is there any way (**configuration of code rules** in Visual Studio) or **tool** to stop (by giving warning or error) developers to use “new” keyword to create instance of service classes.
Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a sort of self-defeating goal to me. To do this, you would have to teach your "new / ignorant" developers to use the tool to validate the quality of their code. or perhaps you can get it to automatically check the code when they commit it? Would it not be better to teach your developers to use an IoC instead, and provide them with the reason and motivation to do so?

Comment: I understand your point of view...but i think it is better to have fool proof system. Further I believe in Albert Einstein as he said "Two Things Are Infinite: the Universe and Human Stupidity" (including me).

Comment: Do you use Resharper? If so, you might be able to configure it to warn about this.

Comment: That would be great if you could devise a fool proof system - I'm just not sure that would be feasible. In the worst case, a false sense of security might just make things even worse. To put it in other words: If your ignorant programmers want to do something stupid, they will probably ignore any warnings you provide, and go ahead anyway. That is, of course, unless you explain the _necessity and benefits_ of using an IoC, so they have the right motivation. _PS: If I remember correctly, Einstein was uncertain about the universe_

Comment: @DavidOsborne we use resharper so could you please guide me how to configure so...if you have done something like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Resharper Code Inspections. Add custom patterns to find the things you want to warn developers about. These settings can then be shared by all developers.

Example: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp80/Reference__Add_Edit_Highlighting_Pattern.html

I would imagine you'll need to define the types you want to inject and then add them into your pattern.

Comment: That's interesting. Could you give an example of a custom pattern that might be of use for the OP in this context?

Comment: I think this is easier said than done (although I'm completely unfamiliar with this R# feature). Typically you want to check that 'certain types of classes' are not references as singletons, but are injected into the constructor using their interfaces. The question really is here how to define those 'certain types of classes' and how to detect that they are references and newed up directly instead of injected through their interface. I'm not sure that the template patterns are flexible enough to do this kind of deep analysis.

Comment: I agree David, food for thought indeed.

Answer (score 3):

You can't force this upon developers using tools. They will always find ways to work around your 'stupid' tools. Instead, you should lead by example, teach them, train them. Do code reviews and explain why what you are suggesting is the way to go.

Comment: Obviously we must teach and train for the awesomeness. But sometime there may be silly mistake. So to avoid those...Is there any way to show at least warning using or without using third party tools in Visual Studio?

Comment: @PraveenPrajapati: Always remember to prefer [Individuals and interactions over processes and tools](http://www.agilemanifesto.org/). If you can't make a team to conform, tools will not help. And since your requirement seems to be especially be 'without thrid party tools', the only solution is: do code reviews.

Comment: Sure...agree with you :-) and it is good to have tools...(otherwise why so many tools are there and recommended for craftsman?)

Comment: @Steven. I disagree. You can use tools to guide and ultimately conform. However, I agree that the tools can only do so much.

Comment: **DO CODE REVIEWS** should be an answer in and of itself... This is a process problem, not a tooling problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have naive / ignorant developers, bad code is going to slip into your project. You should change your process so that code reviews are required before that bad code makes it into your repository.

Note that "ignorant" here does not mean stupid, or bad developers. It just means people who do not know there is a better way to do something. Once you teach them the better way, and they learn that is expected of them, it will erode their ignorance.

Things you can do:

1. Make all junior developers have to submit pull requests in order to submit their changes. Senior / lead developers must then review the changes and either accept them or reject them with changes requested.
2. Put your interfaces under one namespace, and the service implementations under a different namespace. While reviewing, scan files for the service namespace, and if it is used anywhere it is not supposed to be used, reject the pull request.
3. Whenever you observe that a violation of the rule you want to enforce has slipped into your repository, run a BLAME to find out which developer introduced the bad code. Have a talk with that person. Find out why they did it that way, and not the way you prefer. Show them why it is preferable to do it your way.
4. Have unit tests for your code. Sometimes it can be harder to make tests pass when service implementations are hard-coded into the method-under-test instead of mocking the service's interface.

I like [@David Osborne's R# idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28044467/304832), but developers can always suspend R#, or turn it off altogether. Ultimately this is a process issue.  [I agree with @Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28043567/304832) that you should lead by example, teach, and train. Build your team up by sharing your knowledge, don't drag them down by punishing them for doing something incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I got one more and better page explaining how create a **custom code inspection** in ReSharper:
https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp80/Code_Inspection__Creating_Custom_Inspections_and_QuickFixes.html